# Convert binary value of image content to base64 string

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, base64

I'm retrieving previously uploaded image binary content. Now I need to convert it back to a downloadable image. Here is the code I used.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET',httpUrl+ url, true);

    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        alert(this.response);
        var responseArray = new Uint8Array(this.response);
        alert('VAL' + responseArray.length);

        var base64 =btoa(uint8ToString(responseArray));
        window.open("data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64) ;


    };
    xhr.send();
```

What could be the issue here? a new window opens up but the image is not appearing which means the content is not correct. Also i checked with an online converter (using the base64 string i get) and it also doesn't show the image. So basically my conversion is wrong.

Comment: adding method function uint8ToString(buf) {
    var i, length, out = '';
    for (i = 0, length = buf.length; i < length; i ++) {
        out += String.fromCharCode(buf[i]);

    }
    return out;
}